# Google test automation

Tags: googletest

I am a developer, working in C++/unix.

Its compulsory for us to write google-test for whatever new code we add. I feel it really takes some effort.

Can we automate the unit test (google test) ? I mean can we have an automation script which should have the intelligence to create the unit testsuites and it should at least cover 70% of code.

I know this should be difficult,but just curious to know whether this is possible or not.If possible, then what are the concepts i need to learn for this.I consider this as a long term goal,and i can use my free time to learn/develop this.Please help me on this and provide some link/source where i can get some fundamental knowledge on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this concept is fundamentally flawed.

I don't see how such an automated process could possibly deduce the *intent* of the function being tested without referring to the code implementing the function.  If this is the case, and the code has a bug, the test will be automatically created to check for the wrong result.

What would be much more reasonable in my opinion, would be to have a process which automatically creates the gtest boilerplate stuff for every class and function.  So e.g. for every class, it could create an appropriately-named test fixture, and for every public function, a test case.  The actual test cases would probably default to containing only something like:

```
FAIL() << "Test not yet implemented."
```

Some tool like this may well already exist.

This is a far cry from what you're looking to achieve, but it *would* take some of the repetitiveness out of the test process.